# how to get the actual address of `func` from func@PLT on ARM64(gcc-4.9.2-arm64 compiler)

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, elf, dynamic-linking

I have a function test::Foo::bar, the function address of this function in cpp is
(void *) 0x423e70 _ZN4test3Foo3barEiPvml@plt
(gdb) disassemble 0x423e70
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN4test3Foo3barEiPvml@plt:

```
0x0000000000423e70 <+0>:     adrp    x16, 0x513000
0x0000000000423e74 <+4>:     ldr     x17, [x16,#2272]
0x0000000000423e78 <+8>:     add     x16, x16, #0x8e0
0x0000000000423e7c <+12>:    br      x17
```

it seems like the function address is in PLT, and the actual address is contained in x17 Register. I am wondering can I get the actual function address in GOT during runtime in CPP program? Is there anyway I could get absolute function address through PLT address during run time?

Thanks

Comment: You don't get it from the PLT, you get it from the GOT entry.  (The PLT stub *uses* the GOT entry in modern systems, rather than being modified itself.)  Depending on compiler and compile options, taking a function pointer in C++ may choose to load from the GOT instead of just constructing a reference to the PLT entry, on the assumption that cutting out a level of indirection every time the fptr is used will be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, I am using gcc-4.9.2-arm64 compiler. Is there any compile options that could take function pointer load from the GOT? Does  -fPIC help? or should I include -fno-plt. however this is supported after 6.1.1.

Comment: IIRC, `gcc -fPIE` does that.  Or yes, `-fno-plt` will definitely work.  Current GCC is 11 or 12; GCC 6 is already a few years old and pretty stable, so this could be a good reason to justify upgrading to a newer better compiler.